# Binding to arbitrary or nonstandard attributes in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia

In order to use a library, I need to be able to bind to the "for" attribute of a UL element.

This does not work:

```
<ul for="${id}"> ... </ul>
```

Based on testing I assume this is because `ul` elements don't normally have a `for` attribute.   How do I work around this?  This was a trivial in Durandal / knockout which I believed was something like:

`data-bind="attr: { for: $data.id }"`

Do I really have to create a custom attribute?  Is this going to conflict with the built in attribute used for `label`?  Any other obvious workaround?

Comment: No - it's a requirement of the library, so it must be 'for'  https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#menus-section

Comment: That's helpful, but I don't really buy the reasoning.  There is plenty of valid aurelia attributes you can have that aren't 'standard' on a UL element.  I think a simple way to bind to arbitrary attributes should be included, just like it was included in durandal / knockout.

Comment: I think this could be supported. Open a ticket in the templating-binding repo and someone should get back to you with suggestions for a PR.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aurelia absolutely supports binding to ad-hoc/arbitrary properties on a DOM element.

When you write `<ul for="${id}"> ... </ul>` Aurelia is going to assign the value of the `id` property to an ad-hoc property on the `ul` element.

It's the equivalent of doing `ul.for = id` or `ul['for'] = id`.

The part you're missing is *setting an arbitrary **property** on a DOM element does not automagically create a corresponding **HTML attribute**.*  In other words, there's a difference between `ul.for = id` and `ul.setAttribute('for', id)`. This is easy to forget because we typically work with standard html attributes and the DOM has special logic to mirror the value of the HTML attribute with the corresponding DOM property. This special logic does not exist for arbitrary properties that you might add in your code/bindings.

You can force the binding to use `setAttribute` instead of the standard behavior by creating a binding behavior:

https://gist.run/?id=feedfd7659d90c0bdf6d617a244288a6

*set-attribute.js*

```js
import {DataAttributeObserver} from 'aurelia-binding';

export class SetAttributeBindingBehavior {
  bind(binding, source) {
    binding.targetObserver = new DataAttributeObserver(binding.target, binding.targetProperty);
  }

  unbind(binding, source) {}
}
```

**usage:**

```html
<template>
  <require from="./set-attribute"></require>

  <ul for.bind="id & setAttribute"></ul>

  <ul for="${id & setAttribute}"></ul>
</template>
```

---

## EDIT

Aurelia now ships with an `attr` binding behavior. Use `<ul for="id & attr">`. Here's the updated example: https://gist.run/?id=5a12f928d66b6d92c592feb6a62940ad

Comment: This looks like a better solution than mine posted below since it can work for other attributes as well, however I still think this is very unsatisfying.  When I do `id.bind="id"` it sets the id attribute.  When I do `data-foo.bind="id"` it sets the data-foo attribute.  It is surprising and un-intuitive that the default behavior here is to set a property on the DOM element which doesn't even exist.   Furthermore, DataAttributeObserver is not in the docs or even the aurelia-binding.d.ts file.   I still believe aurelia needs a better, out-of-the-box solution for this.

Comment: `id` is a built-in.  Whether you use `setAttribute(id,...)` or `el.id = ...`, the DOM is going to sync the attribute value and the property value. Looking at this very narrowly, with only your use-case in mind, it may seem like the current behavior is undesirable.  For other use cases, the performance implications of calling `setAttribute` for no reason would be a deal-breaker. I do agree there should be more docs. It never hurts to have more docs. The DOM can be confusing. For example, keeping your `for` attribute example, but using a `<label>` element instead, the property is `htmlFor`!

Comment: I see.  I suppose data-* works the same way as id?  Perhaps some sort of attr.bind syntax or similar would be useful.

Comment: `data-*` and `aria-*` work because Aurelia can assume your intent is to bind to the html attributes in those two cases because they're well-known html attribute prefixes

Comment: FYI I got the following javascript error while using this behavior when replacing a parent: `viewmodel: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: binding[behaviorKey].unbind is not a function(…)
unbind @ aurelia-binding.js:1266`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating an attribute for this.

```
export class MdlForCustomAttribute {
    static inject = [Element];

    element : HTMLElement;
    constructor(element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    valueChanged(newValue, oldValue) {
        this.element.setAttribute('for', newValue);
    }
}
```

Usage:

`<ul mdl-for.bind="id">...</ul>`

This kind of scenario may be supported in a future release: https://github.com/aurelia/templating-binding/issues/94